# Plantillas para comentarios

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, interfaz-de-usuario

Buen día,

En el día a día de mi interacción con el sitio me he encontrado que utilizo una y otra vez los mismos mensajes, sería posible que se agregaran opciones de crear y guardar plantillas tanto de comentarios como para utilizar frases en las respuestas? Algo similar a `code snippets` o los enlaces mágicos del sitio que desplieguen un texto predefinido?

Comment: Se que hay algunos shortcodes para los comentarios, poner links con descripción, parte pequeña de código. Saben donde puedo leer mas sobre ellos? o con formular mi comentario como una respuesta y luego pegarla en el comentario bastaría?

Comment: Yo me diseñé un programa en Python que genera un comentario a partir de algunas tildes, tipo "carece de intento" o "tiene una captur de texto". Podrías diseñar algo similar.

Comment: Ah es buena idea! Gracias

Comment: yo tengo una extension que se llama ATSU que es la que uso para algunas ayuda en los comentarios...

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Tras una breve conversasión con @padaleiana me compartió [esta extensión](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) que sirve precisamente para eso, el enlace para la extensión de Chrome está roto en el repositorio.

El método de instalación es un poco confuso para Chrome, hay que instalar primero la extensión [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) y luego visitar [éste](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments/raw/master/dist/autoreviewcomments.user.js) sitio para poder instalarla.

Comment: Se tiene que configurar para que se pueda cambiar a Español o algo?